# Django model two step filter one is user and the other is custo

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am creating a project management app
Each user has multiple projects and each project has a set of data 
When first logged in the user sees a list of all the projects only he created.i am able to do this.
Then when clicked on the project the data related only to that project is to be shown.
How do i do that in django?
My projects model

```
class projectsmodel(models.Model):
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    projects=models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def save_model(self,request,obj,form,change):
        obj.added_by=request.User
        super().save_model(request,obj,form,change)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.projects
```

My BOQ Model,it is the model that needs to be filtered based on project it is redirected from

```
class boqmodel(models.Model):
    project_name = models.ForeignKey(projectsmodel, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    code = models.IntegerField()
    building = models.ForeignKey(building, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    level = models.ForeignKey(level, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(activity, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    subactivity = models.ForeignKey(sub_activity, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    linkactivity = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    linktype = models.CharField(choices=choicestype, max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    linkduration = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    plannedstart = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    plannedfinish = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    actualstart = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    actualfinish = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

html page of projects

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top;">Projects<br>
      </td>
        <td>Open</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
        <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
   {% for projectsmodel in projects1 %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{projectsmodel.projects}}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'projecthome' %}"<button class="btn btn-warning">Open</button></td><a></button>
            <td><a href="{% url 'projectsedit' pk=projectsmodel.pk %}"<button class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button></a></button>
        <td><a href="{% url 'projectsdelete' pk=projectsmodel.pk %}"<button class="btn btn-warning">Delete</button></a></button>

        </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}

  &nbsp; <a class="btn btn-primary" href="createprojects/">Create Projects</a>

{% endblock %}
```

my views for project

```
@login_required
def projects(request):
    projects1 = projectsmodel.objects.filter(added_by   =request.user)
    context = {'projects1': projects1}
    return render(request, 'projectslist.html',context )
```

Comment: Please add code of your models.

Comment: @AmandeepSinghSawhney added both my models

Comment: If possible please add the html page where you are showing projects.Then i will answer your question.If possible add views too.

Comment: each project has a open button next to it.when clicked it is redirected to its bow projecthomepage which should display the boq model with only the projects data

Comment: What is projects1 ? Please add the view. Moreover why are you using CharField for projects in projectsmodel. If a user is adding multiple projects then you should have a separate model of Project and there you will link it with the user and so on.

Comment: thank you .i missed that using charfield .i will change it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204305/discussion-between-raviteja-reddy-and-amandeep-singh-sawhney).

Answer (score 0):

Ok what i have understood. You need a structure like this.

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.IntegerField()
    building = models.ForeignKey(building, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    level = models.ForeignKey(level, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(activity, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    subactivity = models.ForeignKey(sub_activity, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    linkactivity = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    linktype = models.CharField(choices=choicestype, max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    linkduration = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    plannedstart = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    plannedfinish = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    actualstart = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    actualfinish = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

urls.py

```
from yourapp.views import project_details

#Add this url to your url patterns
url(r'^project-details/(?P<projectId><pk>[0-9]+)/$',project_details,name='project_details')
```

views.py

```
from yourapp.models import Project
@login_required
def project_list(request):
    user_projects = Project.objects.filter(added_by=request.user)
    context = {'projects': user_projects}
    return render(request, 'projectslist.html',context )

@login_required
def project_details(request,projectId):
    context = {}
    project_required = Project.objects.get(id=int(projectId))
    context['project']= project_required
    return render(request,"yourapp/projectDetails.html",context)
```

This is projectlist.html .You can add button to open project details. For the sake of simplicity i have not added any extra html element.

```
{% for project in projects %}
<tr>
    <td> <a href="{% url "project-details/{{project.pk}}" %}">{{project.project_name}}</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

projectDetails.html

```
<p>Project Name : {{ project.project_name }} </p>
<p>Project Link Activity: {{ project.linkactivity }} </p>
<!-- and so on -->
```

**P.S: where "yourapp" is the django app you have in your django project**